# Rendering ContainerView's template within a child view

Tags: ember.js

I would like to render the block of a ContainerView within one of the child view's template, so if I have a view such:

```
MainView = Ember.ContainerView.extend({
  childViews: ['child'],
  child: Ember.View.extend({
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{view.parentView.template}}')
  }),
});

Ember.Handlebars.helper('main-view', MainView);
```

Assuming in template I have something like:

```
{{#main-view}}
    SOME CONTENT.
{{/main-view}}
```

This wont work because `view.parentview.template` references a function that Ember set as the template, so, is there a way to make the childView's template refer to the parent's template?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ContainerView doesn't have neither template nor layout :/. It only has the properties to set tagName classNames, etc and then it will render the childViews(buffer) inside it.

A while ago, I was pointing a similar issue: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/3334

Let's hope someone add support to wrapping(layout) for ContainerView, that way you could solve your problem too!

Comment: I assumed so but the template is there, if you invoke the template function you will see the block content get rendered, so I guess it's not too complicated to support it.